# Why wp_enqueue_style() not working?

Tags: themes

I am new to wordpress, I am trying to develop a theme on localhost, I am trying to load style.css using this code in functions.php

```
function add_theme_scripts() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
   }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```

And style.css is

```
body{background:green;}
```

But this code is not working

Can someone explain what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you theme is active?

If you see your style.css code it should not have only the CSS code but also the Theme defination at header of your style.css.

Please make sure if your theme is active.

The above code for loading CSS file looks good and should work if your theme is active.

**Update** :

Have you added `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` in `header.php` and `footer.php` respectively?

`wp_head()` should be added before `</head>` tag in your HTML and `wp_footer()` should be added before `</body>` tag in HTML.

Comment: It does have theme defination and theme is active , but still not working, what to do ?

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Comment: Hey I just add  `wp_header()` and `wp_footer()` , Now it is working, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Style.css is added by default when you make your theme. Why you want to add it through functions.php? You can also call any css in header.php also.

Answer (score 0):

Added `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` in header.php and footer.php file
and make sure make file functions.php to add your files using this two function `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script`